# Simple matplotlib.animation graph geting slower very fast and than stoping

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've started to learn about matplotlib functions because i wanted to visualize data i was receiving via websocket. For that i made a dummy program that mimics the behaviour of my main program but has added the functionality of mathplotlib. what i noticed is the program takes more and more time to finish each loop and eventually 'freezes'. i managed to extend it life by changing the `interval` in `animation.FuncAnimation` from 1000 to 10000. But that just the program to plot sometimes up to 9s for 1 new peace of data. I believe the problem lays in a inappropriate way of cleaning old plots. But i don't know where exactly i did the mistake

```
import time
import datetime
import timeit
import queue
import os
import random
import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

q = queue.Queue()
beta=[0,]
b=False
czas=[]
produkty=["primo"]
cena=[[] for _ in range(len(produkty))]


fig=plt.figure()
#ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
#ax2=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1=plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax2=plt.subplot(1,1,1)
def animate(i):
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax1.plot(czas,cena[0])
    ax2.plot(czas,beta)


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    alpfa=time.time()
    #input('press enter')
    rand_produkt=random.choice(produkty) 
    rand_price=random.randint(1,10)
    rand_czas=time.ctime()
    alfa={'type':'ticker','price':rand_price,'product_id':rand_produkt,'time':rand_czas}
    q.put(alfa)
    if q.not_empty:            
        dane=q.get()        
        typ=dane.get('type',None)
        if typ=='ticker':
            price=dane.get('price', None)
            pair=dane.get('product_id',None)
            t=dane.get('time', None)
            b=True
    if b==True:
        b=False

        produkt_id=produkty.index(pair)
        cena[produkt_id].append(float(price))
        czas.append(t)


    plt.ion()
    ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=1000)#, blit=True)repeat=True)
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.001)
    #fig.clf()
    beta.append(time.time()-alpfa)
    print(beta[-1])
```

Comment: Every millisecond you start a new animation. This means after one second, you already have 1000 animations running, each trying to update the same figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest if I understood You correctly adjusting the interval will not help me I need to find a way to force drawing the plot ONCE per loop.

Comment: Yeah, the solution is to not put the `FuncAnimation` in a loop, because the `FuncAnimation` essentially *is* the loop.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this will be a problem for me. This `while True:` loop is essentially the main part of my main program and it 'glues' everything together. removing `FuncAnimation` from it will meant its newer going to be call upon. Changing the loop to something else will mean fixing again things that are finally working. Ether way i just realize i got a massive design flaw at the very core of my code.

Comment: You may put the code that "glues things together" into the function that is repeatedly called by  `FuncAnimation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you call a new animation in you while loop. Hence this will cause slow down down the line. It is better to initiate your plot ones. One trick may be to update the object data directly as such:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, pause, show
from numpy import sin, pi

fig, ax = subplots()

x = [0]
y = [sin(2 * pi * x[-1])]
p1, = ax.plot(x, y) 

show(block = False)
while True:
    # update data
    x.append(x[-1] + .1)
    y.append(sin(2 * pi * x[-1]))
    p1.set_data(x, y) # update data
    ax.relim()        # rescale axis
    ax.autoscale_view()# update view
    pause(1e-3)
```